# iOS Inhouse App updating when pushing home button

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I'm managing Inhouse Apps.
I'm confused about process of updating Apps btw past and now.

I made a button in Apps for updating.
Before.. when I push the button, Apps going down and updating automatically.
But, now..? when I push the same button, foreground of Apps change nothing and then I try to push the home button. And It was working..!

Anyone knows about this?

Comment: I don’t know what you are asking but as a guess are you getting back on the main thread after going to a network thread

Comment: @agibson007 What means "network thread" in yours? if it means network thread for updating after pushing the button, it's going background thread and starts updating when I pushed a device home button. And doin anything with Apps.

Comment: Show some code and I might be able to help